# Best option for data grid records that each can have different multiple choices

Tags: forms, controls, formatting

Below is a mock up of the screen, and I'm not sure of the best way to do the Delay Reasons in this case.

Each service can have multiple delay reasons and each service can have different delay reasons. Does a button approach work for this? This will normally be setup by an administrator user and not changed too often. Or would it be better to be able to change all delay reasons for all services in one section? If so, what would be the best way to display that?

[image]

Comment: If the reasons are not numerous very long, maybe triggering another window for these is not a good idea? Could you put them in the first window, as a second row below service name? If not, I think your approach is quite good.

Comment: It's hard to say, the delay reasons is a dynamic list that is populated from a different screen. So if the client does not clean it up, it may become quite long.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of popup - with the options shown on the image - I would implement inline editing. Hit the **Edit Delay Reasons** and make the list of checkboxes swipe down under the button. Let all the other lines follow downward and chang the button text to **Save Delay Reasons**. When the user is finished, she hits the save button and all is the original list again.

If the user hits another edit button - nothing is saved on the first record, and the selected item does the same swipe as the first one did.

[image]

Comment: It's a great idea, I just think that more of the empty space could be used, so I wouldn't limit it to the width of the "Delay reasons" column. Reasons can be longer than this column, and both limiting the width of the list that appears and extending the column itself could mean non-optimal usage of the space.

Comment: @DominikOslizlo True that! You could add at least 30 reasons without losing focus.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a button for editing delay reasons, A drop-down of check boxes is ideal solution. The drop-down drops on to the below rows. 
[image]